# Why are child divs overflowing the parent container?

Tags: html, css

I have four 25% width divs not fitting inside a 100% width div.

I'm unsure if this may have something to do with my borders or something.

So this is essentially the design I'm going for..

[image]

This is the result I am getting...

[image]

Here is the code I am using...

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
}

.titleContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  float: left;
}

.graphsContainer {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.graph {
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.graphImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.graphTitle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="titleContainer"></div>
  <div class="graphsContainer">
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be great..

Cheers

Comment: It's not because of the whitespace, the OP is using `float`. However, `box-sizing` is.

Comment: 25% width will be exclusive of border. Because you're adding a border, this pushes the width above 25%.

Comment: @Vucko: my bad, you're right: reopened - although I suspect it's still a dupe (albeit of another question).

Comment: @DavidThomas yes, I also thought that it was a whitespace issue.

Comment: @DavidThomas, if I missed anything let me know :-)

Comment: @Michael_B: nicely done, and *thank you!* Finally, a useful answer, and up-voted :)

Answer (score 3):

To make your layout work add this line of code:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/57r8Ltbh/)

---

### The `box-sizing` property, and the difference between `content-box` and `border-box`.

Here's an illustration of the [**CSS box model**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html):

[image]

With the [**`box-sizing`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property, you have two options for calculating the length of an element.

The property takes two values: `content-box` and `border-box`.

With `content-box` (the default value), the length of the box – either width or height – includes only the *content*  box. Neither the padding, border or margin are factored into the calculation.

In your code, the 25%-width boxes are wrapping because the 25% is applying only to the *content* section. But you also have a 2px border around each element. This means that the width of each box is actually: 25% + 4px. Multiply that by four and you have:

```
25% + 25% + 25% + 25% + 4px + 4px + 4px + 4px = 100% + 16px > 100% = wrapping
```

To counter this effect, CSS offers a second method for calculating length: `box-sizing: border-box`.

With `border-box` the calculation includes the content, padding and border. Hence:

```
25% + 25% + 25% + 25% + 4px + 4px + 4px + 4px = 100% (4px is factored into the 25%)
```

Further reading:

- [MDN `box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)
- [CSS-Tricks `box-sizing`](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)
- [Learn CSS Layout `box-sizing`](http://learnlayout.com/box-sizing.html)
- [Paul Irish * { Box-sizing: Border-box } FTW](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

Answer (score 1):

use this in your style may help you

```
*
{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: While this is true, please could you explain *why* it "may help"? What does it do? What change does it make? Give the OP - and future visitors - something to learn, that they can understand and use again, rather than throwing this into their CSS in the hope of magic.

Comment: The box-sizing property is used to tell the browser what the sizing properties (width and height) should include. and * keeps all the element in box-sizing

Comment: Yes. *I* know. But that should be in the answer, where people are likely to read it.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* you missed this property*/

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
}
.titleContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
.title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  float: left;
}
.graphsContainer {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
.graph {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
  /* gave it for demo purpose*/
  border: 2px solid purple;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
.graphImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.graphTitle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="titleContainer">
  </div>
  <div class="graphsContainer">
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
    <div class="graph"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

You forgot to declare `box-sizing` property. You can read about **Box Sizing** [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) 
Buddy, you can check, what box-sizing is on SO itself.
[What is use of box sizing in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879820/what-is-use-of-box-sizing-in-css)

Comment: And what does `box-sizing` do? Why does it help? Why does its omission cause the observed problem? Yes, *I* know; the OP probably doesn't. Nor, probably, will the future visitors looking for an answer to their own problems, which is who we're trying to help. Teach, don't just give them code to throw at future problems that they don't understand. Please.

Comment: have added the link to explain you, or you can even visit on w3Schools http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: No. Don't just link to a resource, otherwise when that link dies, or when the site falls over or reorganises, the link - and your answer, mostly - becomes immediately devalued. Summarise the information in your answer to explain *here* how it works. Provide a reference link, by all means, but don't *just* post that reference link. Also, w3schools? Sigh. They're atrocious in many ways (though they have improved a little), please consider linking to a reputable source (such as MDN, or the CSS spec that defines `box-szing`).