# How to fix the margin page to the left?

Tags: html, css

How to fix the empty margin left of the page, this issue happened for all the template, Strangely, I did not change the CSS or the index page of the template and it was working and suddenly it changed.

```
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>Admin</title>
    <!-- plugins:css -->
    <base href="/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/iconfonts/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/css/vendor.bundle.base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/css/vendor.bundle.addons.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sweetalert.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css">
    <!-- endinject -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png"/>
</head>
```

Here where I immport JS files

```
<script src="vendors/js/vendor.bundle.base.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/js/vendor.bundle.addons.js"></script>
<script src="js/dashboard.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/sweetalert2.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/association.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

[This is my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c5Jm.png)

and here is the problem 
[image]

Where and how i have to add the CSS please ?

Comment: It's hard to say for certain what the issue is without seeing any of the code you're using. Could you add a little code snippet for folks to test out?

Comment: without code no help can be provided. For infos : in french we say "un document", not "une document". Please clarify your question with at the minimum a sample of code that reproduce your issue

Comment: Looks like a [CSS Box-Sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879820/what-is-use-of-box-sizing-in-css) issue. But we won't know until Yoss creates a [**Minimum Complete Verifiable Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm sorry for that but I don't know where is the problem in the code ! I will show you my index page where I imported all my scripts and CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can often find the answer yourself using Chrome's DevTools.

1. Open DevTools (F12 or right-click on page and choose `Inspect Element`)
2. Click the top-left icon of an arrow pointing inside a box
3. Move the mouse over the area that is having the problem
4. Click
5. In DevTools window, you will see the HTML on the left, and the CSS for the high-lighted HTML tag in the vertical pane to the right. You can experiment here with tweaking different css settings and watching the changes in real time. *(Note: this is just a testing area, no changes are saved to your webpage. When you find the magic, update your page code.)*

[Better CSS Coding with Chrome DevTools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3HGJsNLQ1E)

[How to Debug With Chrome DevTools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VcgcgO26H4)

Comment: I know that, but when open the DevTools, I can't select the area that is having the problem, please check the image above when I inspect the page and move the move on it.