# When window width becomes small it's over the content

Tags: html, jquery, css, responsive

Here's my code:

```js
$("window").load(function() {
  $("#body").removeClass("preload");
});

$(".share-btn").mouseenter(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".item-menu").addClass("visible")
  }, 500);
});
$(".share-btn").mouseleave(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".item-menu").removeClass("visible")
  }, 500);
});
$(".item-menu").hover(function() {
  $(".item-menu").addClass("visible")
});
$(".item-menu").mouseleave(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".item-menu").removeClass("visible")
  }, 500);
});
$(".container-item").hover(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".container-item").css("z-index", "1000")
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

.item {
  width: 96%;
  height: 415px;
  background-image: url(http://sappun.diskn.com/outsidemall/globalsite/promotion/en/200612/product/7-1.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  /*top:0;
    left:0;*/
  z-index: 5;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.item:hover .item-overlay {
  /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
  background: background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 28%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(28%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 28%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 28%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42) 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 28%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42) 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 28%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#6b000000', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-8 */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.item-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 100%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 100%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 100%);
  -o-transform: translate(0, 100%);
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.item:hover .item-content {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.item-content {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
  height: 70px;
  padding: 15px;
}


/*<!-------------------------->*/

#contentWrap {
  width: 69% !important;
  min-width: unset !important;
}

#content {
  width: 100% !important;
}

#bid_4_box {
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.four_inbox {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.four_img {
  width: 97%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.fourbox_text_info {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

.fourbox_product_name {
  font-family: 'heebo', 'Noto Sans KR';
  font-size: 12px;
}

.fourbox_b_price {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #d42c20;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.fourbox_p_price {
  text-decoration-line: line-through;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
  .four_inbox {
    width: 50% !important;
  }
}

.bf_p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1800px) {
  #contentWrap {
    width: 88% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper" id="bid_4_box">
    <div class="four_inbox">
      <section class="row">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="item-overlay"></div>
          <div class="item-content">
            <div class="fourbox_text_info section" id="tt">
              <p class="fourbox_product_name">[SAPPUN BASIC] Kamishu Daily Flip-flop &amp; Slipper (1cm)</p>
              </br>
              <div class="bf_p">
                <p class="fourbox_b_price">22.95 USD</p>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                <p class="fourbox_p_price">45.90 USD</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="four_inbox">
      <section class="row">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="item-overlay"></div>
          <div class="item-content">
            <div class="fourbox_text_info section" id="tt">
              <p class="fourbox_product_name">[SAPPUN BASIC] Kamishu Daily Flip-flop &amp; Slipper (1cm)</p>
              </br>
              <div class="bf_p">
                <p class="fourbox_b_price">22.95 USD</p>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                <p class="fourbox_p_price">45.90 USD</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="four_inbox">
      <section class="row">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="item-overlay"></div>
          <div class="item-content">
            <div class="fourbox_text_info section" id="tt">
              <p class="fourbox_product_name">[SAPPUN BASIC] Kamishu Daily Flip-flop &amp; Slipper (1cm)</p>
              </br>
              <div class="bf_p">
                <p class="fourbox_b_price">22.95 USD</p>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                <p class="fourbox_p_price">45.90 USD</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="four_inbox">
      <section class="row">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="item-overlay"></div>
          <div class="item-content">
            <div class="fourbox_text_info section" id="tt">
              <p class="fourbox_product_name">[SAPPUN BASIC] Kamishu Daily Flip-flop &amp; Slipper (1cm)</p>
              </br>
              <div class="bf_p">
                <p class="fourbox_b_price">22.95 USD</p>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                <p class="fourbox_p_price">45.90 USD</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>
```

When you hover the `img`, it shows *product name* and *price* including `opacity' black background.

The problem is when window size becomes small, that hovers things size over the `img`s.

I'm stuck with this problem and all I want is that `hover` content keeps inside of `img`, it must not depend by window size.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `item` has `96%` width and fixed `415px` height. When you resize window, the with/height ratio of `item` changes and image does not cover entire element.

**Solution 1**

Change `background-size` of `item` to make image always cover entire element:

```
  .item {
     ...
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover; /* add if you want to support Firefox 3.6 */
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
     ...
   }
```

**Solution 2**

If you have square images only (or its with/height ratio is constant), change width and height of `item` as follows:

```
  .item {
     ...
     width: 96%;
     height: 0;
     padding-bottom: 100%;
     ...
   }
```

Adding `100%` padding to the bottom of container and `0` height will make the container height same as width (`100%` refers to container width). To make it work, remember about setting `box-sizing` to `border-box` globally or for your `item` container (Ref.: [What is use of box sizing in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879820/what-is-use-of-box-sizing-in-css/31880256)).

**Solution 3 (best):**

Refactor your HTML and CSS to use flex/grid system and put your images in HTML (not as CSS backgrounds).

Comment: EMiDU... really thank you so much!!!! it perfectly work!! really appreciate! thanks a lot, have a great day!!!! :D